# How to call controller from .php file on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, try-catch

I have name is Bildirim_Islemleri.php  php file on laravel public directory.I need call Controller in this php file.And return cath error to insert log table.How can ı do this?Do you have any ideas?

Im sharing directory stcuture and code.I trying this process in last from function  OdemeBildir [controller directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bff0L.png)

[php file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY0nj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ATG.png)

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */

class Bildirim_Islemleri
{
  // use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;
  function __construct() {
    $yol = "../config/DBConfig.php";
    require_once( $yol );


  }
  public function OdemeBildir($post)
  {
    $dbConfig=new DBConfig();
    $baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbConfig->host.";dbname=".$dbConfig->dbname, $dbConfig->dbuser, $dbConfig->password);
    $baglanti->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $baglanti->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $siparis_kodu=$post["merchant_oid"];
    $sepetGetirSql = "select * from sepetler where siparis_kodu='".$siparis_kodu."'";
    //
    $sepetler = array();


  $queryResultSepetList = $baglanti->query( $sepetGetirSql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
  if ( $queryResultSepetList->rowCount() > 0 ) {
      foreach ( $queryResultSepetList as $row ) {
          array_push( $sepetler, $row );
        }
      }


$uye_id="";
for ($i=0; $i <count($sepetler) ; $i++) {
  $statement = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT urun_adi,urun_fiyati FROM urunler WHERE urun_id = :urun_id");
  $statement->execute(array( ":urun_id" => $sepetler[$i]["urun_id"] ));
  $urun_bilgileri = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  $prepare = $baglanti->prepare("INSERT INTO siparisler SET urun_id = :urun_id,miktar=:miktar,urun_fiyati=:urun_fiyati,siparis_kodu=:siparis_kodu,kargo_takip_no=:kargo_takip_no,odeme_durumu=:odeme_durumu,uye_id=:uye_id");

  $veriler = [
      "urun_id" =>  $sepetler[$i]["urun_id"],
      "miktar" =>  $sepetler[$i]["miktar"],
      "urun_fiyati" =>  $urun_bilgileri["urun_fiyati"],
      "siparis_kodu" =>  $sepetler[$i]["siparis_kodu"],
      "kargo_takip_no" =>  "",
      "odeme_durumu" => 1,
      "uye_id" => $sepetler[$i]["uye_id"]
  ];
  $uye_id=$sepetler[$i]["uye_id"];
  // verileri çalıştır
  $prepare->execute($veriler);


    }
    // $sepet_sil=$baglanti->prepare("DELETE FROM sepetler WHERE siparis_kodu=:siparis_kodu");
    // $sepet_sil->bindParam(":siparis_kodu",$siparis_kodu,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    // $sepet_sil->execute();
    try {
    App\Http\Controllers\MailController::siparisiniz_alindi_mail_gonder("emrahcaliskan33@outlook.com", "Emrah Çalışkan",$siparis_kodu);
    } catch (Error  $e) {
      $this->HataLogKaydet($uye_id,$siparis_kodu,$e->getMessage());
    }



  }
  public function HataLogKaydet($uye_id,$siparis_kodu,$hata_log)
  {

    $dbConfig=new DBConfig();
    $baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbConfig->host.";dbname=".$dbConfig->dbname, $dbConfig->dbuser, $dbConfig->password);
    $baglanti->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $baglanti->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $prepare = $baglanti->prepare("INSERT INTO hata_loglari SET uye_id = :uye_id,siparis_kodu=:siparis_kodu,hata_log=:hata_log");

    $veriler = [
        "uye_id" =>  $uye_id,
        "siparis_kodu" =>  $siparis_kodu,
        "hata_log" =>  $hata_log
    ];
    // verileri çalıştır
    $prepare->execute($veriler);
  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run code in a PHP file directly, completely bypassing Laravel’s routing system?

Comment: Move whatever logic you're trying to invoke into a separate class which you can then call both from the controller, and directly from the other code where you need it. The controller is designed for responding to help requests...you should not try to call it from other php code in the same application.

Comment: Yes,I know but,i have to do like this.BEacause this php file just working asynchronous.And the api I use can only access while in this folder.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only call the controller file, Laravel's core and other Libraries will be missing.

1 - You may move your Bildirim_Islemleri file to App\Http\Controller folder as OdemeBildirController.php and define route on web.php

```
Route::post('odeme/odeme-bildir', [App\Http\Controllers\OdemeBildirController::class, 'OdemeBildir']);
```

This will provide a route for your OdemeBildir function.

2 - If you don't want to use your file with Laravel, then you can communicate with Laravel thanks to queues. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Queue provides you to do jobs in the background. You create jobs and a worker processes them in the background by order. You can use store your queue in DB, Redis, or Amazon SQS. It's up to you but DB is enough in this situation. Instead of calling MailController::siparisiniz_alindi_mail_gonder function, you will add a row in the jobs table. This will store information about your job. Then you need to process it with a worker.

Comment: I cant to move this file controller class.Because sen to me with asynchronous post method from PAYTR.Just working asynchronous  this page.User or me cant access client-side.I need call controller class from this file

Comment: Why not? Can you explain in detail? Because there is no reason to move the file. Also, I gave a second option to use if you still insist to not move then you may use the second way.

Comment: I'll thinking try queue

Comment: I've searched but the queues struct doesn't work for me